# Thinkpad T60 Needs Diagnosing (black screen)

Tags: ubuntu, thinkpad, black-screen-of-death

I was using the computer, it was running fine, then the display spontaneously changed into uniform, vertical stripes, each about a half a centimeter wide. I killed the power, then I restarted, and it was fine for several minutes. However, the problem reoccurred. This process happened several times, each with different output (sometimes random colors instead of stripes, sometimes static, sometimes flickering). The screen soon stopped displaying anything at all upon powering up. The indicator light says the system is on (not sleeping, WiFi registering), but the screen is black.

I know it isn't a screen issue because I tried to use second monitor, and it mirrored the Thinkpad's.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? Also, in the event that this is a catastrophic failure, is there anything I can do to salvage my information?

Model: ThinkPad T60.
OS: Ubuntu 12.04

EDIT: I did the aforementioned on both battery and AC. Also, I just tried again starting up again, and the computer started, booted, but what was displayed was segmented by vertical stripes (i.e. I could see the homescreen through the spaces between those stripes).

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. Please say why you think it should. It looks like a real question to me.

Comment: It is likely a problem with the graphical 'card'. Though depending on the T60 model that 'card' can be intergrated into the chipset (i950 chipset) or be any of these: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-62722 . If that is the case the only options are RMA the motherboard, or use an external graphical card (e.g. which the expresscard slot).

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might check is that your BIOS firmware is up-to-date.  This can cause an array of nasty problems.

It is a procedure you must do very carefully, or you could brick your lappy.  The software required is on the Lenovo website as well as instructions.  The last update was in 2010, but since the T60 is a fairly old model (I am now typing on a T60p), you may not have done this.

Good luck and let us know if this suggestion is at all useful.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, guys. Well, how do I update if my laptop is crippled?

Comment: You can make a bootable CD for this.  It only uses very low level graphical capabilities, and you may be able t see it.  Give it a shot.